# Estimote beacons vs real device

Tags: ibeacon, estimote

I've been working for a while with `ibeacons` and for testing purposes I bought some devices from a company back in Hong Kong for a couple of bucks each. I wish I didn't... They kinda suck, I really understand why they cost so low.

Anyway since I could not come up with anything interesting I started playing with `iPhones/iPads` using a mocking app I created to turn them into `ibeacons`, and the result was way way better than the real hong-kong beacons. I also used the `Estimote` app to turn `iPhones` in live beacons and everything was fine.

I'm asking now, if you ever bought/used `Estimote` beacons, is there any difference between them and an `iPhone/iPad` broadcasting the signal? I mean, is a mocked `iDevice` always better than any beacon you can purchase (say for better hardware components)? Or are just the one I purchased to be sh*t?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly built beacon that meets the specifications of the beacon format will work just as well or better than an iOS device transmitting as a beacon.  I have experience with dozens of different beacon vendors, so I can say this with confidence.

Dedicated hardware beacons are often configurable in ways that iOS devices transmitting as a beacon are not.  With the [RadBeacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-dot) line from [Radius Networks](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/) (my company), you can configure:

- The advertisement rate (from 1 Hz - 10 HZ.)  On iOS, transmission these are locked at 10 Hz and not changeable.
- The transmitter power (from ~5 meter range to ~50 meter range.)  Again on iOS, this is not configurable.  The transmission distance is around 40 meters.
- Different beacon advertisement formats like AltBeacon and Eddystone

One reason that cheap beacons are often poor quality is that they are often powered by a coin cell batter, and take shortcuts to save power.   They often advertise infrequently (say at 0.2 Hz instead of the recommended minimum of 1 Hz), which causes very inaccurate distance estimates, and random entry/exit events.

It is important to note that there are also a number of options for software beacon transmitters different platforms, some of which do allow you to have lots of configurability just like hardware beacons.  Locate for Android, for example, allows you all of the configuration options mentioned above.

- [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) (iOS)
- [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en) (Android)
- [MacBeacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/macbeacon) (OSX)
- [QuickBeacon](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/collections/all/products/quickbeacon-windows-bundle) (Windows)

Full Disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful. I guess the problem with the beacons i purchased is exactly the one you suggested.